# Release memory consumed by images with Twain

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks, twain

Twain scan images to memory and it consumes too much memory. So I scanned images in batch, and compress images in memory. So source images should be released. how can I do it?

```
 protected void OnTwainTransferReady()
            {
                if (TwainTransferReady == null)
                    return; // not likely..

                List<ImageSource> imageSources = new List<ImageSource>();
                ArrayList pics = tw.TransferPictures();
                tw.CloseSrc();
                EndingScan();
                picnumber++;
                for (int i = 0; i < pics.Count; i++) {
                    IntPtr imgHandle = (IntPtr)pics[i];
                    /*if (i == 0) { // first image only
                        imageSources.Add(DibToBitmap.FormHDib(imgHandle));
                        //Refresh(image1); // force a redraw
                    }*/
                    ImageSource src = DibToBitmap.FormHDib(imgHandle);
                    ImageSource temp = ImageHelper.compressImage(src);
                    src = null;
                    imageSources.Add(temp);
                    Win32.GlobalFree(imgHandle);
                }
                // for some reason the main window does not refresh properly - resizing of the window solves the proble.
                // happens only with the Canon LIDE Scanner
                // Suspected: some messages where eaten by Twain
                TwainTransferReady(this, imageSources);
            }
```

Generate the BitSource

```
public static BitmapSource FormHDib(IntPtr dibHandle)
        {
            BitmapSource bs = null;
            IntPtr bmpPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            bool flip = true; // vertivcally flip the image

            try {
                bmpPtr = Win32.GlobalLock(dibHandle);
                Win32.BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi = new Win32.BITMAPINFOHEADER();
                Marshal.PtrToStructure(bmpPtr, bmi);

                if (bmi.biSizeImage == 0)
                    bmi.biSizeImage = (uint)(((((bmi.biWidth * bmi.biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3) * bmi.biHeight);

                int palettSize = 0;

                if (bmi.biClrUsed != 0)
                    throw new NotSupportedException("DibToBitmap: DIB with pallet is not supported");

                // pointer to the beginning of the bitmap bits
                IntPtr pixptr = (IntPtr)((int)bmpPtr + bmi.biSize + palettSize);

                // Define parameters used to create the BitmapSource.
                PixelFormat pf = PixelFormats.Default;
                switch (bmi.biBitCount) {
                    case 32:
                        pf = PixelFormats.Bgr32;
                        break;
                    case 24:
                        pf = PixelFormats.Bgr24;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        pf = PixelFormats.Gray8;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        pf = PixelFormats.BlackWhite;
                        break;
                    default:   // not supported
                        throw new NotSupportedException("DibToBitmap: Can't determine picture format (biBitCount=" + bmi.biBitCount + ")");
                    // break;
                }
                int width = bmi.biWidth;
                int height = bmi.biHeight;
                int stride = (int)(bmi.biSizeImage / height);
                byte[] imageBytes = new byte[stride * height];

                //Debug: Initialize the image with random data.
                //Random value = new Random();
                //value.NextBytes(rawImage);

                if (flip) {
                    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = (height - 1) * stride; i < height; i++, j += stride, k -= stride)
                        Marshal.Copy(((IntPtr)((int)pixptr + j)), imageBytes, k, stride);
                } else {
                    Marshal.Copy(pixptr, imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }

                int xDpi = (int)Math.Round(bmi.biXPelsPerMeter * 2.54 / 100); // pels per meter to dots per inch
                int yDpi = (int)Math.Round(bmi.biYPelsPerMeter * 2.54 / 100);

                // Create a BitmapSource.
                bs = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, xDpi, yDpi, pf, null, imageBytes, stride);
                Win32.GlobalUnlock(pixptr);
                Win32.GlobalFree(pixptr);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                string msg = ex.Message;
            }
            finally {
                // cleanup
                if (bmpPtr != IntPtr.Zero) { // locked sucsessfully
                    Win32.GlobalUnlock(dibHandle);
                }
            }
            Win32.GlobalUnlock(bmpPtr);
            Win32.GlobalFree(bmpPtr);

            return bs;
        }
```

Compress Image in Memory

```
internal static System.Windows.Media.ImageSource compressImage(System.Windows.Media.ImageSource ims)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (MemoryStream outS = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    BitmapSource bs = ims as BitmapSource;
                    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                    BitmapFrame bf = BitmapFrame.Create(bs);
                    //encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image1.Source));
                    encoder.Frames.Add(bf);
                    encoder.Save(stream);
                    stream.Flush();

                    try
                    {
                        // Read first frame of gif image
                        using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(stream))
                        {
                            image.Quality = 75;
                            image.Resize(new Percentage(0.65));
                            image.Density = new Density(200, DensityUnit.PixelsPerInch);
                            image.Write(outS);
                            image.Dispose();
                        }

                        stream.Close();
                        stream.Dispose();
                        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                        bitmap.BeginInit();
                        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                        outS.Position = 0;
                        bitmap.StreamSource = outS;
                        //
                        bitmap.EndInit();
                        //bitmap.Freeze();
                        outS.Flush();
                        outS.Close();
                        outS.Dispose();
                        ims = null;
                        return bitmap;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: I've never used it before, but I doubt twain.net suffers from memory leaks, unless you're using it wrong (have you disposed everything that's disposable?) or there's a bug in your twain drivers. In general, the answer to 'how should memory be released' is dependent on how the memory was allocated in the first place. Since you haven't posted any code, we don't know.

Comment: @zeromus code is attached

Comment: I don't see any memory leaks here, although I may have missed something. Are you using so much memory that you run out of memory? Or do you just not like how much it's using? Are you sure you're not just accumulating a lot of jpeg compressed images in memory? Could you try processing everything except for the actual TWAIN part (skip converting the GDI bitmap and compressing it). You seem to have skipped a lot of easy mistakes here so I hate to ask such dumb questions...

Comment: this 32 bit application can only handle 100 pics. And memory reaches 3G. 5 pics can consume 100M unmanaged memory. Does `FormHDib` has something is not free since `ImageSource` `src` will not be used?

Comment: From what I can see, src is pure managed stuff. How big are these pictures? If it's practical, I would suggest tearing down the whole twain system between each scan (just see if it helps, for informational purposes). In case the twain system or drivers are keeping some memory, that might get it cleaned up.